# Replace a bunch of if-else conditions with scikit-learn

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, scikit-learn

I'm trying to wrap my head around ML with scikit-learn

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "f1": [1, 1],
    "f2": [0, 0],
    "c":  [1, 0]
})


#df
f1 f2 c     # f1, f2 - features / c - class/ classifier
1  1  1     # for f1 = 1 and f2 = 1 > expected c = 1
0  0  0     # for f1 = 0 and f2 = 0 > expected c = 0


dtc_clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

features = df[["f1", "f2"]]
labels   = df[["c"]]

dtc_clf.fit(features, labels)

test_features = pd.DataFrame({"ft1": [1, 1], 
                              "ft2": [0, 0]})

#test_features
ft1 ft2  #I added for test exactly the training data
1   1
0   0


dtc_clf.predict(test_features)

#I'm getting this result:
#array([0, 0])

#I expected this result
#array([1, 0])
```

If '1,1 => 1' then '0, 0 => 0' 
It should be 'array([1, 0])' right?

Each column is a condition which if it's respected will be 1 if not 0. 
Basically I'm trying to replace a lot of if else conditions with ML.

Comment: Are you abusing a ML technique to replace if-else conditions? this is a complete wrong approach, ML is never a if-else condition. ML is for prediction only and not for assigning rules to something, try to use a vectorized solution instead of ML techniques

Comment: why not? If I have a score of 100% and it works as expected with less code?

Comment: But ML is not made for this, you are running into the risk, that you miss a case...there are tons of functions in python to to this if-else stuff, you can use dictionaries, mappings, apply, where....., please really don't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with DecisionTreeRegressor

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

# "beer": 1
# "wine": 2

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "boy": [1, 0],
    "hetero": [1, 1],
    "drink": [1, 2]
})


X = df[["boy", "hetero"]]
y = df[["drink"]]


regr = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0)

model = regr.fit(X, y)

# Make new observation
observation = [[1, 1]]


# Predict observation's value 
model.predict(observation)

Result :

array([ 1.])
```